# How to generate array of years till current year?

Tags: javascript

In below code I can generate array of years but it's not dynamic. Year should start from 1901 to `current year` and in reverse order.

```js
const theDates = [];
let cell = 1900;

for (let x = 0; x < 24; x += 1) {
  const row = [];
  
  for (let y = 0; y < 5; y += 1) {
    row.push(cell += 1);
  }
  
  theDates.push(row.reverse());
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(theDates.reverse()).toString());
```

Currently, I am generating years till `2020` but I am hard-coding it. I need something like below, say that this is year `2023`

```
[[2023,2022,2021,2020,2019], ... [1903,1902,1901,null,null]]
```

At any given point in time there should be 5 items in the inner array and last empty array values can be `null`

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the year with `new Date().getFullYear()`, then you can push chunks of 5 while the year number is greater than 1901:

```js
const theDates = [];
for (let year = new Date().getFullYear(); year !== null;) {
  const row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++, year = (year > 1901 ? year - 1 : null)) {
    row.push(year);
  }
  theDates.push(row);
}
console.log(theDates);
```

Example of year other than 2020:

```js
const theDates = [];
for (let year = 2023; year !== null;) {
  const row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++, year = (year > 1901 ? year - 1 : null)) {
    row.push(year);
  }
  theDates.push(row);
}
console.log(theDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but according to [google](https://tecadmin.net/get-current-date-time-javascript/) you can do something like

```html
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
```

since getFullYear() – Provides current year.